# fragment of sliding pane layout is transparent for clicking

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingpanelayout

I'm using sliding pane layout in my project. When it was in its closed state i tried to click on an empty space of my fragment's layout, but the click was performed on another fragment (which should be shown only when sliding pane layout is in open state), like it's on the top of the screen. It looks like empty RelativeLayout's space is transparent for clicking. Is there a bug or am I doing wrong something?

Comment: Here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181749/click-events-on-slidingpanelayout/24796663#24796663